# Iterate through folders in azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I've a requirement like: I've three folders in azure blob container, and inside those three folders have three zip files and the zip files contains respective source files (*.csv) with same structure. I want to loop through the each folders and extract each of the zip files into an output folder then I want to load all the three csv files into target sql table. How can I achieve this by using azure data factory?

```
Azure storage account
      productblob (blob container)
            Folder1 >> product1.zip >> product1.csv
            Folder2 >> product2.zip >> product2.csv
            Folder3 >> product3.zip >> product3.csv
```

I've already tried to loop through the folders and got the output in Foreach iterator activity but unable to extract the zip files.

Answer (score 0):

After looping to ForEcah activity, you could follow the following steps:

- Select a binary dataset and give file path as Foreach output(by creating a parameter in Dataset and in Source defining the value to this parameter). Select compression type as ZipDeflate.
- In the sink, select the path where you want to save the unzipped files. (Select Flatten hierarchy in Sink if you want only the files.)

Comment: Hi @Prachi Thanks. In my case I've two pipelines first one reading from the folders and other I created for selecting each folder files (child) and I created the binary dataset with a ds parameter but when I tried executing it still captures the folders only. not the inner contents i.e. zip ones. could you please share me the demo screenshots. Thanks

Comment: I'm new and don't know how to share screenshots..till the time I try figuring that out, you could create two foreach activities. But remember, you cannot do it in a single pipeline. For that in one pipeline try doing the steps I mentioned and in another pipeline try using execute pipeline activity inside foreach and iterate through folders.

Comment: I've already tried that before you mentioned but its not happening either. In my 2nd pipeline also, the o/p reads the folder names but not the childitems :( I've already set the parameters for getting the folder path & filename dynamically but in the 2nd pipeline (inner one) it does not capture the zip files (pipeline does not fail)... I'm still trying